# FastAPI keeps throwing an error loading (ASGI app)

Tags: python, command-line, frameworks, fastapi

the file name is **main.py** anytime i run `uvicorn main:app --reload`
i get the error under the code.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Error

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/Documents/main.py']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [58745] using statreload
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the command uvicorn main:app --reload in the same directory as the file main.py is? Probably that's your problem.
I tested your code and it is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

check that the name of your file should be main or if that's name is 'example' you shuld write: uvicorn example:app --reload